# Preserve previous pagination and search filter after Add/Update of record

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have this scenario that I need to keep the current pagination and search filter on my employee list after I have added or updated an employee record. Since I am using GET method for pagination and search filter, I am planning to keep the URL after add/update action so that the user will be redirected to the employee list with current search filter and page number.

**My question now is should I keep this URL in Session or better store it in a table?** The URL will be removed once the user go to other modules (e.g. department, subject, etc).

I am using Laravel 4, maybe they have a function that I can use for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flashing it to the session would probably be the easiest way to do this.

`Session::flash('key', 'value');`

Comment: In addition to your answer, I have also used URL::previous() to capture the URL on the following functions:

public function create() {}
public function edit($id) {}

Thanks!